# React.js and DataGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I must use a datagrid with my React.js project.I try a couple of datagrid but I couldn't find what I want.

The datagrid must have good looking in smaller pixels.For example when you enter the screen with the mobile phone the datagrid must have good looking.

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you write what are the datagrid you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](http://zippyui.com/react-datagrid/#/) datagrid - 
it should work good for you.